# Github destop MAC don't see 'commit & sync' button

Tags: github-for-mac, github-desktop

before i was able to `'commit & sync'` (button) my new changes from my local repo to remote. Now i have 2 new commits but i only see `Commit to Develop`. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Commit and Sync" button is activated from the Edit menu, by checking the "Automatically Sync after Committing" entry.
This option is only available on Mac OSX.